# How to specify tie-breaking logic in boost dijkstra_shortest_paths (dijkstra)

Tags: boost

The background for my question is well explained in this SO question
[Is Dijkstra's algorithm deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379178/is-dijkstras-algorithm-deterministic)

Concretely, the answer by [@Wyck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563833/wyck) illustrates the use-case I want to solve.
Image provided by @Wyck
[image]

My requirement is that boost's `dijkstra_shortest_paths` (based on the provided graph) when asked to produce a path from 0 to 5, always produces: 0->1->5, because the tie-breaking logic should use the lowest sum of the node IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for lack of code, here's your sample codified with BGL:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e49b47c3f9c44d6)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct VertexProps { };
struct EdgeProps { double weight = 1; };
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                    VertexProps, EdgeProps>;
using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using E = Graph::edge_descriptor;

Graph make_graph();

int main() {
    auto g = make_graph();
    //write_graphviz(std::cout, g);

    std::vector<V> predecessors(num_vertices(g));
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, 0,
                                   boost::weight_map(get(&EdgeProps::weight, g))
                                       .predecessor_map(predecessors.data()));

    std::cout << "Path: ";
    for (V v = 5; ; v = predecessors[v]) {
        std::cout << " " << v;
        if (v == predecessors[v])
            break;
    }
}

Graph make_graph() {
    // sample from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649312/how-to-specify-tie-breaking-logic-in-boost-dijkstra-shortest-paths-dijkstra
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);
    add_edge(0, 3, g);
    add_edge(0, 4, g);
    add_edge(1, 5, g);
    add_edge(2, 5, g);
    add_edge(3, 5, g);
    add_edge(4, 5, g);

    return g;
}
```

Which prints

```
Path:  5 1 0
```

But if we reverse the order in which the edges are added:

```
Graph make_graph() {
    Graph g;
    add_edge(4, 5, g);
    add_edge(3, 5, g);
    add_edge(2, 5, g);
    add_edge(1, 5, g);
    add_edge(0, 4, g);
    add_edge(0, 3, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);
    add_edge(0, 1, g);

    return g;
}
```

It now prints **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/021d8c202fc6217f)**

```
Path:  5 1 0
```

It seems that the graph model dictates the examination order. Let's fixate by using an ordered container selector (like `setS`) for edge storage:

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                    VertexProps, EdgeProps>;
```

Now we can have a random insertion order:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
Graph make_graph() {
    // sample from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649312/how-to-specify-tie-breaking-logic-in-boost-dijkstra-shortest-paths-dijkstra
    using namespace std;
    vector ee{pair{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4},
              {1, 5},     {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}};
    shuffle(ee.begin(), ee.end(), mt19937{random_device{}()});

    Graph g;
    for (auto [s, t] : ee)
        add_edge(s, t, g);

    return g;
}
```

And still always get (**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e72fb2d9401271f1)**):

```
Path:  5 1 0
```

### Verifying The Solution!

Code without tests is broken. Let's throw a wrench in the works:

```
Graph make_graph() {
    vector ee{
        tuple //
        {0, 1, 1.0},
        {0, 2, 1},
        {0, 3, 1},
        {0, 4, 1},
        {1, 5, 2.0},
        {2, 5, 1},
        {3, 5, 1},
        {4, 5, 1},
    };
    // shuffle(ee.begin(), ee.end(), mt19937{random_device{}()});

    Graph g;
    for (auto [s, t, w] : ee)
        add_edge(s, t, EdgeProps{w}, g);

    return g;
}
```

Note how we increased the weight for the `1 -> 5` edge alone. Now we get **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481cb8059c336bf0)**

```
Path:  5 4 0
```

Soooo... We expected 5 2 0 here. I decided to record an animation of the actual progress of the BFS search: **[Code On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df2b6c6e6f0f9d3e)**:¹

[image]

It becomes clear now that the intermediate queue  favors later discoveries. We need to tweak the priority comparison.

### Custom Weight Type

Let's try to hack it with a custom `Weight` type instead of `double`:

```
struct Weight {
    double magnitude = 0;

    bool operator<(Weight const& rhs) const { return magnitude < rhs.magnitude; }
    bool operator==(Weight const& rhs) const { return magnitude == rhs.magnitude; }
    bool operator!=(Weight const& rhs) const { return magnitude != rhs.magnitude; }
    Weight operator+(Weight const& rhs) const {
        return {magnitude + rhs.magnitude};
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Weight const& w) {
        return os << w.magnitude;
    }
    static Weight Inf() { return {std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()}; }
};
```

*Mutatis mutandis*, this still works the same: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4462e6d062e89998)**.

Of course, now the challenge becomes to include the "cumulative node ID sum" into the equation:

```
struct Weight {
    double magnitude = 0;
    size_t cumulative_node_id_sum = 0;

    auto both() const { return std::tie(magnitude, cumulative_node_id_sum); }

    bool operator<(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() < rhs.both(); }
    bool operator==(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() == rhs.both(); }
    bool operator!=(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() != rhs.both(); }
    Weight operator+(Weight const& rhs) const {
        return Weight{magnitude + rhs.magnitude,
                      cumulative_node_id_sum + rhs.cumulative_node_id_sum};
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Weight const& w) {
        return os << w.magnitude;
    }
    static Weight Inf() {
        return Weight{std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), 0};
    }
};
```

Still the same (Live). Why? Because no initial weight actually knows the node id:

[image]
Let's initialize in `make_graph`:

```
for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
    g[e].weight.cumulative_node_id_sum = target(e, g);
}
```

This sets the initial node ID sum to just the vertex ID for the target of each edge. With that in place, it all clicks:

[image]

And indeed the path is back to the desired:

```
Path:  5 2 0
```

### Simplify/Cleanup

With that all understood, we can probably do lipo-suction on that diagnostic code. We sprinkle a tiny bit of magic so the [default expression for `distance_inf`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html#:%7E:text=Default%3A%20std%3A%3Anumeric_limits%3CD%3E%3A%3Amax()) works:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31eef8c48d7c5fad)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::literals;

using Traits = boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>;
using V      = Traits::vertex_descriptor;
using E      = Traits::edge_descriptor;

struct Weight {
    double magnitude              = 0;
    size_t cumulative_node_id_sum = 0;

    Weight(double magnitude = 0, size_t cumulative_node_id_sum = 0)
        : magnitude(magnitude)
        , cumulative_node_id_sum(cumulative_node_id_sum)
    { }

  private:
    auto both() const { return std::tie(magnitude, cumulative_node_id_sum); }

  public:
    bool   operator<(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() < rhs.both(); }
    bool   operator==(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() == rhs.both(); }
    bool   operator!=(Weight const& rhs) const { return both() != rhs.both(); }
    Weight operator+(Weight const& rhs) const {
        return Weight{magnitude + rhs.magnitude,
                      cumulative_node_id_sum + rhs.cumulative_node_id_sum};
    }
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct numeric_limits<Weight> : numeric_limits<double> {
    };
} // namespace std

struct EdgeProps {
    Weight weight;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                    boost::no_property, EdgeProps>;

Graph make_graph();

int main()
{
    auto g = make_graph();

    std::vector<V> predecessors(num_vertices(g));
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths( //
        g, 0,
        boost::predecessor_map(predecessors.data())
            .weight_map(get(&EdgeProps::weight, g)));

    std::cout << "Path: ";
    for (V v = 5;; v = predecessors[v]) {
        std::cout << " " << v;
        if (v == predecessors[v])
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
Graph make_graph()
{
    // sample from
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649312/how-to-specify-tie-breaking-logic-in-boost-dijkstra-shortest-paths-dijkstra
    using namespace std;
    vector ee{
        tuple //
        {0, 1, 1.0},
        {0, 2, 1},
        {0, 3, 1},
        {0, 4, 1},
        {1, 5, 2.0},
        {2, 5, 1},
        {3, 5, 1},
        {4, 5, 1},
    };
    shuffle(ee.begin(), ee.end(), mt19937{random_device{}()});

    Graph g;
    for (auto [s, t, w] : ee)
        add_edge(s, t, EdgeProps{w}, g);

    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        g[e].weight.cumulative_node_id_sum = target(e, g);
    }

    return g;
}
```

Printing the trusty

```
Path:  5 2 0
```

---

¹ images combined using `gifsicle -l -O9 -k32 -d 100 frame{0..31}.gif > test.gif`

Comment: The full code for the animation-rendering version of the code is included inline in an XML comment (anti-bitrot). Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/138b8949-669e-4a9a-bfc4-ee2e3de3cbae/view-source#:~:text=also%20inline%20for%20anti-bitrot) for direct access

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I hope that one day, I could explain something as clearly as you did here.

Comment: Most of it probably is mastery of the tools - I even cheated past some "end bosses" (e.g. the named parameters overload of the algorithm appears simply broken), or the way I inherited `numeric_limits<Weight` (which subtly hinges on conversion constructability from `double`). I'm glad it helped you understand of course!

Comment: Let me take this moment to mention what I forgot to  explicitly say: the final solution works regardless of the edge container (so e.g. [`vecS` works just the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a5c514a786fc2b)). Note that chaning the vertex container can have an avalanche effect: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b90470d4ac38a14 or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/709c73f5e4a37998. This is due to the fact that the implied vertex index is gone.